# hibernate criteria search through multiple entities

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three entities: Log, Employee, and Agency

Log with a many to one association to Employee

Employee with a many to one association to Agency

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Log.class);

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(c.getName())) {
      criteria.createAlias("employee", "e").add(Restrictions.ilike("e.name", "%" + c.getName() + "%"));
    }
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(c.getAgency())) {
      criteria.createAlias("employee", "e").createAlias("agency", "a").add(Restrictions.ilike("e.a.name", "%" + c.getAgency() + "%"));
        }
```

The above works for Employee name, but it doesn't work for Agency name.

I get the below error:

```
Exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: agency of: com.example.Log
```

All the examples I find only go one level down.  Can someone point me to a resource that tells me how to navigate lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Log.class);
criteria.createAlias("employee", "e");

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(c.getName())) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("e.name", c.getName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(c.getAgency())) {
    criteria.createAlias("e.agency", "a"); //  <===========
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("a.name", c.getAgency(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
}
```

Comment: Both answers work, but I ended up going this route because of the cleaner presentation.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The second one should work like this:

```
criteria.createAlias("employee", "e").createAlias("e.agency","a")
           .add(Restrictions.ilike("a.name", "%" + c.getAgency() + "%"));
```